# SSIS Package Login failed while executing as Scheduled Job

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have Created SSIS package which selects data from Source DB and Inserts it in my Destination DB. All the Connections string are Working fine as the Test Connection  is Succeeded when i debug the package.

My package Executes well when i run it in Visual Studio. But If i try to run it as Scheduled Job in SQL Server . It gives me error as

> Data Flow Task ADO NET Source [1]  "Login Failed for user 'ags' for
>   Source Database"

My Source DB is remotely Located.

Package Settings :

```
EncryptAllWithPassword
```

SQL Agent Settings

```
Owner : uagsrep (My SQL Server User)
Type : SQL Server Integration Service Package
Run AS : SQL Server Agent Service Account
```

Database is SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Job executes SSIS Package using System Account. Check if System account has permission on Source Database.

**Refer:** [Running SSIS Package using Non System Account](http://yogeshblogger.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-run-sql-server-agent-job-using.html)

Comment: What if it doesnt have permission on Source DB ?

Comment: You have to create Proxy on account having permission in Source database and use this proxy to run the SSIS package.

Comment: Can u explain more on this ? How to create Proxy account for SSIS ?